# how to filter XML attributes in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok- here's a painfully easy one I bet --

I'm aware of how to use EX4 to filter most pieces of the xml I need

- however how can I filter an XML list such as the one below to check
  say ---  if a dog is a beagle?  preferably as a Boolean.

> var theXml:XML =
>
> ```
>  <animals>
>    <animal dog ="poodle" cat="Siamese" />
>    <animal dog ="beagle" cat="calico" />
>    <animal dog ="mutt" cat="tabby" />    
>  </animals>
> ```
>
> var animalList:XMLList =
>   theXml.animals.animal;

---

this ended up working ( thanks Tyler )...

```
if (theXml.animals.animal.(@dog == "beagle").length > 0) {
    trace('match')
}
```

thanks ! -MW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love the power of E4X, here's the example of what you are looking for:

```
theXml.animals.animal.(@dog == 'beagle');
```

If it finds a match it'll return it.

**EDIT**

To answere your question below:

```
var xml:XML = <a id="34"></a>;

//traces
if (xml.(@id == '34').length() != 0) {
    trace('match')
}

//no trace
if (xml.(@id == '35').length() != 0) {
    trace('match')
}
```

Comment: thanks... hmmm -- so how would I use it -- see altered example above " //both of these return true "

Comment: Updated my response above with example. Goodluck!

Comment: To understand why your trace shows nothing, look into the toString() method on XML objects, it behaves a little funny, and not how you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the root node "animals":

```
theXml.animal.(@dog == 'beagle');
```